# How to split two html tag on one file into separated lucene document?

Tags: perl, lucene

I have html data like this :

```
<DOC>
<DOCID> D1-111 </DOCID>
<TITLE> this is title </TITLE>
<TEXT>
This is content
</TEXT>
</DOC>
<DOC>
<DOCID> D1-112 </DOCID>
<TITLE> this is title on D1-112 </TITLE>
<TEXT>
This is content on D1-112
</TEXT>
</DOC>
```

how to create each content inside `<DOC></DOC>` is one lucene document so based on html data i have 2 lucene document ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, what is **lucene document**?

Please see the following code, I extract data into two arrays - one with `<DOC></DOC>` and other without it included.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my $data = do { local $/; <DATA> };

$data =~ s/\n//g;

my @blocks1 = ( $data =~ m!(<DOC>.*?</DOC>)!g );
my @blocks2 = ( $data =~ m!<DOC>(.*?)</DOC>!g );

print Dumper(\@blocks1);
print Dumper(\@blocks2);

__DATA__
<DOC>
<DOCID> D1-111 </DOCID>
<TITLE> this is title </TITLE>
<TEXT>
This is content
</TEXT>
</DOC>
<DOC>
<DOCID> D1-112 </DOCID>
<TITLE> this is title on D1-112 </TITLE>
<TEXT>
This is content on D1-112
</TEXT>
</DOC>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try this:

```
my $str ='<DOC>
<DOCID> D1-111 </DOCID>
<TITLE> this is title </TITLE>
<TEXT>
This is content
</TEXT>
</DOC>
<DOC>
<DOCID> D1-112 </DOCID>
<TITLE> this is title on D1-112 </TITLE>
<TEXT>
This is content on D1-112
</TEXT>
</DOC>';

my $fcnt = 1; 
while($str=~m/<DOC[^>]*>((?:(?!<\/DOC>).)*)<\/DOC>/gs)
{
    my $docf = $&; my $filename = "Lucena\_$fcnt\.txt";
    writeFile($filename, $docf); $fcnt++;
}

sub writeFile
{
    my ($file, $cnt) = @_;

    open(FILE, ">", $file) || die "Couldn't write the file: $!\n";
    print FILE $cnt;
    close(FILE);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if you would like to preserve *newline* in blocks then code will be following

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my $data = do { local $/; <DATA> };

my @blocks1 = ( $data =~ m!(<DOC>.*?</DOC>)!sg );
my @blocks2 = ( $data =~ m!<DOC>(.*?)</DOC>!sg );

print Dumper(\@blocks1);
print Dumper(\@blocks2);

__DATA__
<DOC>
<DOCID> D1-111 </DOCID>
<TITLE> this is title </TITLE>
<TEXT>
This is content
</TEXT>
</DOC>
<DOC>
<DOCID> D1-112 </DOCID>
<TITLE> this is title on D1-112 </TITLE>
<TEXT>
This is content on D1-112
</TEXT>
</DOC>
```